# IndexError: list index out of range, make a sum of a list

Tags: python, list, index-error

I just wan't to calculate the sum of `Ic[n][0 until 12]` and save it in nw =  list(), but... it doesn't work. I get an error that tells me the `"list index is out of range"`. I don't now how to fix it. Her is the code:

```
    for n in range(0, 12):
        for r in range(0, 12):
            nw[n] += Ic[n][r]
    print nw
```

Here are the values in

```
Ic = [[-0.058763399720191956, -0.42418426275253296, -0.1281072050333023, 0.15460245311260223, -0.05813126266002655, -0.09746139496564865, 0.013134755194187164, 0.49814605712890625, -0.14812283217906952, 0.10285533964633942, 0.11999548971652985, 0.39407849311828613, -0.004134092479944229, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], [2.5735421180725098, 2.1772024631500244, 0.28750336170196533, 0.02845955640077591, -0.5908316373825073, -0.7313328981399536, -0.5317823886871338, 0.19332526624202728, -0.7856833338737488, -0.38039201498031616, -0.4801616072654724, -0.2276214212179184, -0.5854479670524597, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], [..]]
```

The above structure is repeated 50 times.

Comment: which list does it say is out of range?

Comment: File "C:\work\svn\HWFw\Transistor Kennlinienfeld  Messger�t\trunk\bipolar_stromsteuerkennlinie.py", line 54, in bipolar_stromsteuerkennlinie
    nw[n] += Ic[n][r]
IndexError: list index out of range,    this is the exact error message @CasparWylie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have defined `nw=[]` and then you are trying to assign `nw[0] = 123` .  This will throw an error. Try :

`nw =[sum(x[:12]) for x in Ic[:12]]`